# Is it possible to get all the struct that conform to a given protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

### Question

- Is it possible to get all the `struct` that conform to a given `protocol`?
- If so, what are the possible methods?

### Details

I want to get all `struct` that are compliant with `PreviewProvider`.
And we want to access those `_allPreviews`.

For example, to get the `class` that are compliant with an arbitrary `protocol`, you can use the following method.

```swift
import Foundation

class Runtime {
    
    public static func allClasses() -> [AnyClass] {
        let numberOfClasses = Int(objc_getClassList(nil, 0))
        if numberOfClasses > 0 {
            let classesPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass>.allocate(capacity: numberOfClasses)
            let autoreleasingClasses = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass>(classesPtr)
            let count = objc_getClassList(autoreleasingClasses, Int32(numberOfClasses))
            assert(numberOfClasses == count)
            defer { classesPtr.deallocate() }
            let classes = (0 ..< numberOfClasses).map { classesPtr[$0] }
            return classes
        }
        return []
    }
  
    public static func classes<T>(conformTo: T.Type) -> [AnyClass] {
        return self.allClasses().filter { $0 is T }
    }
}
```

[[Swift] To retrieve classes at runtime which conforms to a protocol or to retrieve subclasses of a given class](https://gist.github.com/codelynx/bb72bf0bed58a327ce1dbe6639d0369b)

I'm trying to find something that corresponds to the `struct` of this.

I'm not sure if it's possible at first, but for example [**Sourcery**](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) (**Sourcery** is a code generator for Swift language, It extends the language abstractions to allow you to generate boilerplate code automatically.) seems to be achieved by writing the following.

`{% for type in types.based.PreviewProvider %}`

So I think it's possible.

If you have any advice, I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: but why do you want to do this? How you can guarantee that any struct will implement your custom protocol? You also will lose compile time checks in case of using this kind of runtime magic...

Comment: @VitaliiGozhenko
Thanks for your comment!
This is because I want to get all the PreviewProvider compliant structs, create a UIImage from the content, and save it as a screenshot. I could write it manually, but it's a lot of work, so I thought it would be easier if I could get the PreviewProvider compliant ones in code.

Comment: from my point of view it is completely wrong from architecture point of view. I would rather implement some template autogeneration using Sourcery and Stencil syntax

Comment: @VitaliiGozhenko Thanks for the advice. I agree with you.
I will use Sourcery etc.